# Factorization homology of a braided (n-1)-category on an (n-1)-sphere

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, higher-category-theory, higher-algebra

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a braided ($n-1$)-category. I will assume that $\mathcal{B}$ is a fully-dualizable object in some $n+1$-category of braided ($n-1$)-categories. Hence, from $\mathcal{B}$, using the cobordism hypothesis, one gets a TQFT $\int_{\Box}\mathcal{B}$.

I have read recently that $$\int_{S^{n-1}_b}\mathcal{B} = \Omega^{n-1}\mathcal{B},$$
where $S^{n-1}_b$ denotes the $(n-1)$-sphere with its blackboard framing, and $\Omega^{n-1}\mathcal{B}$ denotes the $1$-category of $(n-2)$- and $(n-1)$-endomorphisms of the monoidal unit of $\mathcal{B}$.

Why is that true?

Comment: Where have you read this?

Comment: This is not true. The only case I've thought of, n=2, ie an ordinary braided tensor category, integrated over the circle in the blackboard framing (aka the annulus), is the topic of the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.04769.pdf and is definitely not the loop of the category, which is trivial eg for B=Rep_q G.

Comment: Ah sorry I think what you mean by looping is a little confusing at least to me. Do you mean the endomorphism category of the unit in the [in fact monoidal] 2-category of B-modules? AKA the categorical Drinfeld center? in which case this is correct

Comment: Very informally at least this is true since you can write the sphere as two discs glued together, which suitably interpreted gives endomorphisms of the disc, considered as an object in the higher category attached to its boundary, which is what this looping operation is (or must be - I think it's important to emphasize you're not thinking of the braided category as a [n-1]category but as a higher category using the monoidal structure). You also need enough duality to make this picture work.

Comment: This is claimed on page 16 of: https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.06663

Comment: Oh, I see! I think that's also where my confusion came from! @DavidBen-Zvi your assumptions are spot on. So if I'm understanding you correctly, this seems true, but has not been formally proven yet?

Comment: Thank you for checking the details, JeCl. I agree something is not parsing in that section of my paper. If nothing else, my notation is poor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an error in my paper. Thank you for finding it. The overall result is correct, but the proof is wrong as written. To correct it, I need to replace "TQFT" with "relative TQFT", and replace $S^{n-1}_b$ with the pair $(D^n, S^{n-1}_b)$, and the rest is correct. In detail:
$\newcommand\cB{\mathcal{B}}\newcommand\cX{\mathcal{X}}$

I want to appeal to a "state-operator correspondence", which for an absolute (aka nonanomalous) $(n+1)$-dimensional TQFT $\cX$ says that the $m$-category of operators of dimension $\leq m$ is $\cX(S_b^{n-m})$. Note that, counting dimensions, this is indeed an $m$-category.

But I wanted to apply this to the relative (aka anomalous) $(n+1)$-dimensional TQFT $\cB$, and its compactification $\cB^2 = \int_{S^1_b}\cB$. This $(n+1)$-dimensional TQFT is relative to an $(n+2)$-dimensional TQFT which depends only on the Morita equivalence class of $\cB$, and my notation did not distinguish these.

So I need to tell you about the state-operator correspondence for relative TQFTs. To say it, let me remind that a relative TQFT is the type of thing that can eat a "cobordism with boundary". This is a manifold with two types of boundaries: you can stitch cobordisms together along one of the types of boundaries, and the other type of boundary is marked by a boundary condition.

I don't have good notation. I will write $\cB_\partial$ for the relative TQFT in question. Suppose $M^m$ is an $m$-dimensional cobordism and I decide that $N^{m-1} \subset \partial M$ is where I will place the boundary condition (and I leave the rest of $\partial M$ as stitchable); then I will write $\cB_\partial(M, N)$, and I won't try to use footnotes. Any absolute $(n+1)$-dimensional TQFT $\cX$ gives a relative $(n+1)$-dimensional TQFT $\cX_{\partial}$ in which $\cX_\partial(M^m,N^{m-1}) = \cX(N^{m-1})$ depends only on $N$. On the other hand, any relative TQFT gives an absolute TQFT in which you only use cobordisms without boundary.

With this all said, the state-operator correspondence for relative $(n+1)$-dimensional TQFTs asserts that the boundary operators of dimension $\leq m$ in $\cX_\partial$ is $\cX_\partial(D^{n+1-m}, S^{n-m}_b)$, where $D^{n+1-m}$ is the disk and $S^{n-m}$ is its full boundary. So this is a cobordism from $\emptyset$ to $\emptyset$.

Ok, now I can compute. I want to show that the multifusion $(n-1)$-category $\cB^e$ is fusion, which is to say that the relative $n$-dimensional TQFT $\cB^e_\partial$ satisfies $\cB^e_\partial(D^n , S^{n-1}) = \mathbb{C}$. As in my paper, use that $\cB^e_\partial$ is a compactification on $S^1$ on $\cB_\partial$, so that what we want to compute is $\cB_\partial(D^n \times S^1, S^{n-1} \times S^1)$. But I can do this by first compactifying on $(D^n, S^{n-1})$ to get an absolute 2D TQFT defined by the 1-category $\cB_\partial(D^n, S^{n-1})$, and we already said that that is precisely the 1-category of boundary lines, i.e. what I called $\Omega^{n-1}\cB$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, this has helped me a lot! If I may ask two more questions: I do not really understand what you mean by $\mathcal{B}_{\partial}$? What morphisms does it correspond to? And, to make sure I understand you correctly, the state-operator correspondence is some physical principle you use in order to justify defining $\Omega^m\mathcal{B}$ the way you do?

Comment: As I said, I don't have good notation. I think the correct proof is now on arXiv. In any case, what I called $B_\partial$ is supposed to be the relative TQFT corresponding to "$B$ as a $B$-module". This is a relative TQFT valued in $Mor_2((n-1)KarCat)$. Or you could suspend (you have enough dualizability) to think about it as "$\Sigma B$ as a $\Sigma B$ module" which selects a relative TQFT valued in $Mor_1(nKarCat)$.

Comment: As for the "state operator correspondence", on the one hand it is a physical principle. On the other hand, I am asserting that if you contemplate (relative) TQFTs and factorization algebras enough, then it will be manifestly true.